# Sort an array or array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want the below array to sort. I want to add the total if the name comes multiples times. Also I want the number to be rearranged. It can be index + 1.

```
array (
  0 => array ('name' => 'Dave', 'number' => '1', 'total' => 1),
  1 => array ('name' => 'Tom', 'number' => '2', 'total' => 1),
  2 => array ('name' => 'Dave', 'number' => '3', 'total' => 2),
  3 => array ('name' => 'Amy', 'number' => '4', 'total' => 1),
);
```

To

```
array (
  0 => array ('name' => 'Dave', 'number' => '1', 'total' => 3),
  1 => array ('name' => 'Tom', 'number' => '2', 'total' => 1),      
  2 => array ('name' => 'Amy', 'number' => '3', 'total' => 1),
);
```

Any idea?

Comment: it's grouping, not sorting

Comment: 1. it looks like PHP, if it is, please tag the question as such. 2. This is too broad, what have you tried ? show us your code where, in specific, you encountered an issue. Remember, we're here to help you, not do you work for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using custom `$group` array and `array_values` function:

```
$arr = array (
 array ('name' => 'Dave', 'number' => '1', 'total' => 1),
 array ('name' => 'Tom', 'number' => '2', 'total' => 1),
 array ('name' => 'Dave', 'number' => '3', 'total' => 2),
 array ('name' => 'Amy', 'number' => '4', 'total' => 1),
);

$group = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (isset($group[$item['name']])){
        $group[$item['name']]['total'] += $item['total'];
    } else {
        $group[$item['name']] = $item;
    }
}
$result = array_values($group);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dave
            [number] => 1
            [total] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tom
            [number] => 2
            [total] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Amy
            [number] => 4
            [total] => 1
        )
)
```

---

***Update:*** If a `number` key should reflect the sequence position of each item use the following approach with the custom `$count` variable:

```
...
$group = [];
$count = 1;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (isset($group[$item['name']])){
        $group[$item['name']]['total'] += $item['total'];
    } else {
        $item['number'] = $count++;
        $group[$item['name']] = $item;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I want the last `[number]` => 4 to be `[number] => 3`

Comment: @iamkdev, by what logic?

Comment: it should be the position of the array. Above example last element index was 2 and position of that is 3. So, it should be 3. Its like serial number.

Comment: by that logic why the item with  `'name' => 'Tom'` has `'number' => '2'` in your expected result while its initial position is `1` ?

Comment: It is just serial no. 1,2,3,4...
After grouping there will be less array. e.g. 1,2,3,4 become 1,2,4
I want 1,2,3

I can do it with another foreach loop but want to avoid that.

Comment: @iamkdev, check my update